# The reason for the SQL to XML exception 'XML parsing: line 1, character 16, undeclared prefix'?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

(Probably not related to C#, simulated also in SSMS using the SQL language)

I am tayloring the C# command-line utility to process the data, store them in SQL Server tables, and then to convert it to XML, and store it in another table.

When doing that, I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'XML parsing: line 1, character 16, undeclared prefix'

However, I am using exactly the same approach in another utility written for another customer -- no problems are observed in the same situation. The truth is that the utility is older (compiled few years ago) and it works in a bit different environment.

**More details**

The application collects data from a text file (DELFOR message, but that should not be important), stores the headers and the data separately into the dedicated SQL tables, and then the user-defined SQL function `ufn_delfor_message_to_xml(@message_reference_number, ...)` is used to get the XML form of the joined tables.

The XML result should be obtained as a string into the C# code:

```
string xmlFormOfTheMessage = DbUtil.ExecuteScalar(
            "SELECT dbo.ufn_delfor_message_to_xml(@message_reference_number, @xml_nad_info)",
            new Hashtable {
                { "message_reference_number",  UniqueMessageReferenceNumber() },
                { "xml_nad_info", xmlNadInfo }
            }).ToString();
```

where the `DbUtil.ExecuteScalar()` is my helper to wrap the Microsoft `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` (this works in many other situations, no error expected in the wrapper).

When trying to find the reason, I got rid of the C# code using only the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to duplicate the error.

When using the code:

```
DECLARE @message_reference_number varchar(55) = '1_022723.4443311'
DECLARE @xml_nad_info XML = '<delfor_nad_info><nad_info><party_identifier>0941B66333840</party_identifier><name>22723</name><street>xxxxxx</street><city>yyy</city><postal_code>08191</postal_code><country_identifier>ES</country_identifier><duns></duns><created>2022-09-06T20:02:46</created></nad_info></delfor_nad_info>'

DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = dbo.ufn_delfor_message_to_xml(@message_reference_number, @xml_nad_info)
SELECT @x
```

it works just fine. The final `SELECT @x` shows the XML representation. However, when avoiding the `@x` XML variable and moving the function to the SELECT, the same error appears:

```
SELECT dbo.ufn_delfor_message_to_xml(@message_reference_number, @xml_nad_info)
```

[image]

For the case, the full code of the SQL function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_delfor_message_to_xml
    (@message_reference_number varchar(55),  -- grp+UNH+documentID
     @xml_nad_info XML)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml_scheduling XML = (
    SELECT -- [message_reference_number],
           --,[document_id],
           --,[line_item_identifier],
           --[item_identifier_by_buyer],
           delivery_plan_commitment_level_code,
           datetime1,
           datetime1_function_code_qualifier,
           frequency_code,
           quantity,
           unit_code,
           datetime2_function_code_qualifier,
           datetime2
      FROM delfor_scheduling_data AS scheduling
     WHERE message_reference_number = @message_reference_number
     ORDER BY datetime1
       FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS)
    -- SELECT @xml_scheduling

    DECLARE @xml_result XML

    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schema.xxxxxxx.xx/dm/externalMessage' AS dat)
    SELECT @xml_result = (
    SELECT [interchange_sender],
           [interchange_recipient],
           [datetime_of_preparation],
           [interchange_control_reference_id],
           [dat:work_order].[message_reference_number],
           [dat:work_order].[document_id],
           [message_function_code],
           [document_issue_datetime],
           [type_of_instruction],
           [dat:work_order].grp,
           [dat:work_order].[seller_identifier],
           [dat:work_order].[shipfrom_identifier],
           [dat:work_order].[plant_identifier],
           [dat:work_order].[buyer_identifier],
           @xml_nad_info,
           [dat:detail].shipto_identifier,
           [dat:detail].[item_identifier_by_buyer],
           [dat:detail].[item_identifier_by_seller],
           [dat:detail].[engineering_change_number],
           [dat:detail].[other_material_characteristics],
           [dat:detail].[material_description],
           [dat:detail].[is_supply_for_consignment],
           [dat:detail].[location_of_discharge_code],
           [dat:detail].[purchase_order_number],
           [dat:detail].[document_line_identifier],
           [dat:detail].[transport_document_reference],
           [dat:detail].[new_delivery_schedule_number],
           [dat:detail].[new_delivery_instruction_date],
           [dat:detail].[previous_delivery_schedule_number],
           [dat:detail].[previous_delivery_instruction_date],
           [dat:detail].[planner_contact_employee_code],
           [dat:detail].[planner_contact_employee_name],
           [dat:detail].[cumulative_quantity_received],
           [dat:detail].[cumulative_quantity_received_unit_code],
           [dat:detail].[cumulative_quantity_received_date],
           [dat:detail].[cumulative_quantity_scheduled],
           [dat:detail].[cumulative_quantity_scheduled_unit_code],
           [dat:detail].[cumulative_quantity_scheduled_date],
           [dat:detail].[cumulative_quantity_received_and_accepted],
           [dat:detail].[cumulative_quantity_received_and_accepted_unit_code],
           [dat:detail].[last_received_delivery_note_number],
           [dat:detail].[last_received_delivery_note_date],
           @xml_scheduling AS [dat:address_info]
      FROM delfor_message_info AS [dat:work_order]

           JOIN delfor_scheduled_article_details AS [dat:detail]
           ON [dat:detail].message_reference_number = [dat:work_order].message_reference_number
              AND [dat:detail].document_id = [dat:work_order].document_id
              AND [dat:work_order].message_reference_number = @message_reference_number

       FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
    )
    RETURN @xml_result
END
```

Can you suggest what could cause the exception? Why the older utility in the older environment works in the same situation? Could there be any new restrictions in the newer environment that would cause the exception?

Comment: My "could be yet another problem with scalar UDF inlining" sense is tingling. What version of SQL Server, and what compatibility level? Ever since the release of this feature there's been a [steady stream of bugfixes](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining#requirements). There are various ways to turn it off if it is the issue; if you value compatibility more than any performance improvements this might bring, turning it off completely with `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING = OFF` is your best bet.

Comment: including `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`  was apparently added as a blocker to inlining in CU11 (from the link above) - are you on a build before that?

Comment: Thanks both @JeroenMostert and Martin Smith. The SQL server is of the version 15.0.2000.5, and the Compatibility level is set to 150. I have found that the SQL function was initially created also for other purpose. However, I can completely avoid the problem when converting the function into the form of the stored procedure. Please write your observations as the comment. I will accept it.

Comment: If you are still on RTM, you should really schedule an upgrade to the latest version ([CU17, as of writing](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2019x)), as aside from a ton of bugfixes in scalar UDF inlining, you're missing a few important security updates, including a fix for a privilege elevation vulnerability. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" doesn't apply here. :P

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I am not the only user of the SQL server, and I am not the maintainer. I have to live with what I have. :]